# Frametitle Numbering

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I am writing in beamer mode
I added `allowframebreaks` on my begin frame command like this

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{frame title here}
```

when slide changes , i get frame title like this

```
frame title here 1  
frame title here 2
```

what to do not to have frame title numbering!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post full (but minimal) examples, others can copy and test as is. Here we have to guess, and not everyone want to bother with doing so.

Answer (score 3):

You can define an empty `frametitle continuation` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thnx bro! i was using \setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second]{} and even then i got (contd.) from the second frametitle. With your example i have no numbering!